# Load Balancing using SQL Server and TempData MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, load-balancing, tempdata

I've been told that MVC 1.0 TempData does not work under a load balancer when using SQL Server and that it is because the Dictionary itself is not serializable.

We require this for a project and are looking to be able load balancer effectively.

So I would be very grateful if someone could answer the following questions:
Is there away around this so you can make it work?
Is this fixed in MVC 2.0?
Can we create a ITempDataProvider to fix it?
Or has anyone made a fix to the source code for a project of their own they would like to share?

Cheers,
Jamie

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary itself doesn't need to be serializable. It is what you store inside `TempData` that needs to be serializable. So for example if you have the following class

```
[Serializable]
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

You can perfectly fine use SQL server for session persistence and write the following code:

```
TempData["foo"] = new Foo { Bar = "bar" };
Session["foo"]  = new Foo { Bar = "bar" };
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm, so any UI model (ASP.Net MVC) would just require the Serializable attribute and that should just work?

How does it work for lists and collection based UI models?

Comment: The generic collection classes are serializeable as long as the type they are storing can be serialized.  (Note that normally you will want to add a comment or edit your question rather than add an answer.)

Comment: Good point! Right I might have a bash at that this week then. Cheers.